# Sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

I want to calculate

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{2^k} $$

Usually (assuming it was $k$ instead of $k^2$) I would consider this as a special case of the series $ f(x) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot z^k $ (i.e when  $z=1/2$)

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k \quad=\quad \frac{z}{1-z}  $$
Derivation gives
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot z^{k-1} \quad=\quad \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}  $$

Multiplying by z
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot z^k \quad=\quad \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}  $$

And if $z=1/2$ it would be 2. But I have no idea how to handle the case when we have $k^2$, any tips?

Comment: At the last stage, you can differentiate again to get $\sum k^2 z^{k-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, just repeat again.